# Fast percona "like" queries, need some explanation

Tags: mysql, percona

I have following sql query:

```
select a,b from table left join table2 on ... 
   where
     table.date > (some date) and 
     table.date < (some date) and
     table.first not like '%condition1%' and
     table.first not like '%condition2%' and
     table.first not like '%condition3%' and
     table.first not like '%condition4%' and
     table.first not like '%condition5%'
limit 500 offset 500
```

"table" - is a very big partitioned tabled, such as AFTER index on date is applied we are getting about 4.2M rows to scan for further where filtering.

So this query works very fast - in about 250ms, how this is possible? Don't we teached not to use like in any way on big tables, especially in such a way where % is applied in both directions?

Also of course "table" - does not have any index on "first" column. Percona version is quite old - 5.5.61-38.13.

How this behavior can be explained?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i got this. The problem was that my query was lacking "order by". Adding order by to this query boosts query time to 6 seconds - which MAKES sense now.

So in previous situation mysql was just looking for ANY data matching the 5 like pattern regardless of sort, which now explains why it was working so fast in addition to 500 limit offset

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you will avoid `LIKE` Searches With Leading Wildcard.
The database will not use an index when using like searches with a leading wildcard (e.g. `'%condition1%'`). Although it's not always a satisfactory solution, please consider using prefix-match LIKE patterns (e.g. `'TERM%'`).

**Best practice example:**

```
SELECT
  id,
  text
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  text LIKE 'TERM%';
```

**Bad practice example:**

```
SELECT
  id,
  text
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  text LIKE '%TERM%';
```

Also, `OFFSET` clauses can be very slow when used with high offsets (e.g. with high page numbers when implementing paging). Instead, use the following seek method, which provides better and more stable response rates.

**Best practice example:**

```
SELECT
  name,
  age,
  department
FROM
  employees
WHERE
  (id, age) > (5000, 40)
ORDER BY
  id,
  age
LIMIT
  10;
```

**Bad practice example:**

```
SELECT
  name,
  age,
  department
from
  employees
where
  age > 40
ORDER BY
  age
LIMIT
  10 OFFSET 5000;
```

Disclaimer: I am EverSQL's co-founder, and you can automatically speed up your query @ EverSQL online SQL optimizer